# More efficient way to embed a .html file on wordpress than Iframe?

Tags: wordpress, performance, iframe, folium

I have several, quite large html files. Each file represents a map created with python/ folium. Each of these files is automatically generated every 48 hours (due to some API authentification renewals), and also uploaded automatically to my wordpress media every 48 hours.

I want to display these maps on my site, currently I am using Iframe like this:

```
<div class="container">
<iframe src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/example.html"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="map"></iframe>
</div>
```

It all works perfectly, however, due to the map/ file sizes (~20 - 30 Mb), the loading time is quite high.
I was wondering, if there is a more efficient way to embed the files.

I tried to solve the problem using Caches, but it was not really satisfying. The creation of the Cache caused an even longer loading time for first-time-visitors, which is currently nearly everyone.

Due to the re-creation of the maps every 48 hours it is not a solution for me to embed the html code directly and I cannot reduce the file sizes.

Comment: If you put them straight up in a directory? - You have to load them as a part of another page?

Comment: Hi @billybadass, I don't really get what you mean with putting them straight up in a directory. Yes, the maps are one part of the pages, however definitely the major part. I have around 20 maps, each on a separate page, but there is also a menu widget on each page.

Comment: Are you embedding the HTML you indicated into a post or page as part of the content? Or are you placing it directly in a template .php file?

Comment: Hi @artlung. I embedded them in a post as part of the content yes.  However there is not much other content, normally just a menu bar or sometimes an Iframe of another website

Comment: And is the html file the only part of the include, or does it also have other content inside `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/` ? Like images, JavaScript, CSS?

Comment: @artlung The html is the only part to include. But inside the html leaflet/folium map there are is also JavaScript yes, to define all the functions the map should do, things like:
function zoomButton(lat, lng, zoom){
                    map_x.flyTo(new L.LatLng(lat, lng), zoom, {animate: true,duration: 1.5});
                    }
            var marker_x = L.marker(
                [39.9, 37.7],
                {"opacity": 0.7}
            ).addTo(feature_group_x);
        var custom_icon_x = L.icon({"iconSize": [30, 30], "iconUrl": "data:image/png;base64,ig=="});
        marker_x);

Comment: An HTML file that large is going to be an issue regardless. I think it would be nice to be able to let an editor do something like `[embed_folium_page src="wp-content/uploads/example.html"]` in the editor. So you create a shortcode that pulls in the file. But with dependent assets you end up having to replace any asset src paths so they work. So then you need a parsing step to rewrite paths in link and src's to be correct for the page slug. So you want to cache that as well. Ultimately how much of WordPress do you want alongside these pages is the question.